# How to invoke a web service in a jBPM Drools project?

Tags: web-services, drools, jbpm

Is there a way to create a service task using a WSDL to call a SOAP web service? I have tried to use the domain specific processes, but I can't find where to put the URL of the WDSL file.

Comment: What's the connection with Drools?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the 'Service Task' for that.  It's under the 'Task' category under designer, or just create a Task and change it to type Service Task.  Change the service implementation to web service and it has properties like interface and operation you need to specify.

Maybe take a look at the following example:
https://github.com/droolsjbpm/jbpm/blob/master/jbpm-workitems/src/test/resources/BPMN2-JaxWSServiceTask.bpmn2

Comment: Thank you for your answer Kris! i will have a look at it!